# How to read very large files from Java REST API and stream it to ANGULAR on UI?

Tags: java, angular, rest

I have to write a REST API code in JAVA so that I stream data of a very large file to UI which is on Angular 5.

Please suggest me with a sample code. I used -

```
String base64encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(line.getBytes("utf-8"));
```

to send as a JSON response to UI. But this is not a good idea as this does not work for very large file. Also, this takes good time in processing the data.

Comment: *But this is not a good idea as this does not work for very large file. * Why? what is the problem?

Comment: REST API in Java is a bit of a broad sense, do you use a framework ? What is a very large object, how much ?

Comment: "line" variable mentioned contains the entire file content. File size can be of 2-3 GB. This results in memory out of heap space.